# Use regex or unix to select specific columns

Tags: java, regex, unix

I am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("df") to get the space details for my partitions.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb12      41022792 4219168  34713128  11% /
udev             8103980       4   8103976   1% /dev
tmpfs            3245332     924   3244408   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             8113328     160   8113168   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb2         262144   28584    233560  11% /boot/efi
```

How can I use regex or UNIX commands to get as the output just the 2nd,3rd and 4th columns - changing the headers as follows - Available Memory, Used Memory and Total memory exactly in this order.

 So the desired output is :

```
Available    Used     Total
34713128   4219168    41022792
8103976       4       8103980
3244408      924      3245332
             ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is most definitely a job for `awk`, not `regex`. Would that be OK?

Comment: as long as I can execute it all in getRuntime().exec(...), Yes!

Comment: Do you want the text centered like that for the middle column, or is right-aligned preferred (as in the original command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rather long string does what you ask:

```
df | awk 'BEGIN {print "   Available        Used       Total";} {if (NR>1)  printf("%12d%12d%12d\n", $4, $3, $2);}'
```

Explanation:

```
| awk          take the output of the df command as input to awk
BEGIN          do this first: print headers. Note the use of spaces to align things
if (NR > 1)    skip "record 1" = do not do anything with the headers
printf()       do formatted printing
%12d           print integer in fixed width of 12 characters (maintains alignment
```

Result on my machine:

```
   Available        Used       Total
    71644456   551306776   623463232
           0         372         372
           0           0           0
           0           0           0
   407510704   377391216   784901920
   618400760   549288520  1167689280
```

Not terribly useful without the name of the disks, but this is what you were asking...

Comment: Happy to help - clearly the above can be modified in many ways and I hope you will… `awk` is really the perfect tool for this kind of thing, well worth becoming familiar with it. It can be obscure, but is surprisingly powerful. Best reference I found is the grymoire (unusual word meaning "book of spells") - written by Bruce Barnett. Google `grymoire awk`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to do this:

```
df | awk '{print ""$4" "$3" "$2""}'
```

Comment: I modified the order.  I'd not try to do a modification of the headers in a Unix command; just do the substitution against the resulting Java string.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works

```
df | perl -pe \
  's!^(?:\S+\s+){2}(\S+)\s+(\S+).*!"$1\t$2\t" . ($1 eq "Used" ? "Total" : $1 + $2)!e'
```

It's not nice: It finds the columns as non-blanks separated by blanks, which is a bit fragile. It computes the last column as the sum or "Total" based on the column name. Rather fragile, I'd say.